# Good logging framework for ActionScript 3 projects

Tags: actionscript-3

I'd like to found some logging framework for AS3. For now I use trace() and debug version of Flash Player, but I'm looking something that can be enabled without having debug version installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more then a couple of logging frameworks.
I really like 2

1. as3commons logging
2. MonsterDebugger

I use them both in projects.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you just want to view trace output with DebuggingPlayer that's no problem - download a program called "Vizzy Flash Tracer", it's just a proxy that listens for output from .swfs and displays it, with filtering options built in. Very useful, it's saved my ass many times!

Get it here: http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/